# Query design issue

Tags: mysql

I have a nested list in this table `address`:

```
name        |lft | rgt |
------------+----+-----+
Australia   | 1  | 10  |
nsw         | 2  | 9   |
sydney      | 3  | 8   |
kensington  | 4  | 5   |
kingsford   | 6  | 7   |
------------+----+-----+
```

Table explanation:As you can see the Australia includes all the others below it from the left and right value. the same applies to nsw and sydney, they contain what's below them. kensington and kingsford have the same depth and they belong to sydney.

I am trying here to write a query for an auto complete search. I want when I type 'k' I get these results:

```
-->kensington, sydney, nsw, australia
-->kingsford, sydney, nsw, australia
```

The current query:

```
   'SELECT parent.name
        FROM  address AS node,
                address AS parent
        WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
                AND node.name LIKE ' . $input
```

the query that I have does return the same values but "mixed up" as follows:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => australia
        [name_en] => australia
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => australia
        [name_en] => australia
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => NSW
        [name_en] => NSW
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => NSW
        [name_en] => NSW
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => sydney
        [name_en] => sydney
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => sydney
        [name_en] => sydney
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => kensington
        [name_en] => kensington
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => kingsford
        [name_en] => kingsford
    )
```

The result that I seek is this

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => australia
        [name_en] => australia
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => NSW
        [name_en] => NSW
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => sydney
        [name_en] => sydney
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => kensington
        [name_en] => kensington
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => australia
        [name_en] => australia
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => NSW
        [name_en] => NSW
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => sydney
        [name_en] => sydney
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => kingsford
        [name_en] => kingsford
    )
```

It should return path after another.

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Why are they repeating and what happens when you use distinct?

Comment: They are repeating because I have two results and they are within sydney,nsw,australia. therefore, "sydney,nsw,australia" is repeating as I have two paths. distinct will eliminate the repeating and this is not favorable as I want which belong to which so I can create paths I as I mentioned above how they should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT parent.name
    FROM  address_tmp AS node,
            address_tmp AS parent
    WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
            AND node.name LIKE 'k%' order by node.lft, node.rgt, parent.rgt
```

(i used k as example for the query)

Comment: I got this order: `australia,kensington,nsw,sydney, australia,kinsford,nsw,sydney`

Comment: Why do you have node.rgt in the order by clause? If you only have one tree like the original example all the node.lft value will be distinct.